# Combining different table queries in db with PHP and displaying all results on one page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have been trying to create a database for fun to get a better understanding of databases and using PHP to query them for a website I'm messing around with. Pretty much I have one database with 4 tables when a user enters a search term in a PHP search box my code searches the database for any entries containing the search term. Now I can easily get my code to search individual tables, but I cannot seem to get it to search all 4 tables and display the results on the same page.

info: making a database for skyrim

- **Table names:** classes, powers, skills, shouts
- **column names:** name, information

Here is a snippet of the code I have that works so far:

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("
   SELECT *
   FROM   `xaviorin_skyrim`.`shouts` , `xaviorin_skyrim`.`classes`
   WHERE  (CONVERT(`UID` USING utf8) LIKE '%".$query."%' OR
          CONVERT(`Name` USING utf8) LIKE '%".$query."%' OR 
          CONVERT(`Information` USING utf8) LIKE '%".$query."%')
") or die(mysql_error());`
```

Literally all I thought I would need to do is change the table name from "shouts"  to say "classes" in a new `raw_results` line of code but that didn't work. I have attempted unions and joins and either keep screwing them up or just don't understand how to properly format them.

```
echo "<p><h3>".$results['Name']."</h3>".$results['Information']."</p>";
```

The code above this text is what displays the results on the page on my website... it works but I don't know how to combine the information from all 4 tables into one page. If I'm going about this in the wrong way and anyone can point me in the right direction I would GREATLY appreciate it... I've been trying to research the problem without finding a proper answer for near a month now.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that relational databases do a cross join when there are several query results from two different tables. So basically every match in one table will be combined with every match from the second table. When you have 3 entries in the first and 4 in the second table, you will get `3 * 4 = 12` entries in your query result. If you add more tables, you get even more results. You want to do a full text search in several tables that are totally unrelated, thus creating some kind of non-existing relation via cross joining them will not be useful.

What you actually want to do is a `UNION ALL` (`UNION` is slower because it prunes duplicates) of several queries:

```
SELECT name, information, 'shouts' AS tablename FROM shouts WHERE ...
UNION ALL
SELECT name, information, 'classes' AS tablename FROM classes WHERE ...
```

This will do search queries on every single table and then place the results in a single result. Also note that I added a third column to each query to ensure that the originating table is not lost after merging the results.

Unless you need to do some sorting afterwards, I would suggest that you do all statements separately. Combining them this way will most likely make the post-processing more complex. And several single queries will also be faster than one big query with `UNION` statements.

And as I mentioned in the comments: Don't use `mysql_*` functions!

Comment: Thank you Till Helge Helwig. Since I am trying to teach myself php i had no idea that the functions were deprecated. I'm going to take some time to try to go over the PDO stuff as it seems like the better option. But thank you for explaining everything to me. If I end up getting it to work I'll post back here with what I got.